# usb-device number changes over time

Tags: linux, usb, raspberry-pi, lsusb

I am trying to use on my RP a camre usb device - Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270.
When I connect it directly to the USB port of the RP, other USB devices stop working (such as WIFI device) I guess this is due to power consumption of the camera.
So I connect the camera to the RP using a power-outsourced USB hub,

I can see the the RP recognizes the hub just fine (lsusb)
but the camera device rapidly shows and disappears from lsusb output. and when it shows it is always with different device number...

Attached here is a sample of a few `lsusb` outputs - that were type one after the other -

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 214b:7000
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 049: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270

lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 214b:7000
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 214b:7000
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 055: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 214b:7000
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 060: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
```

Comment: This sounds like disconnects. What does `dmesg` say?

Comment: dmesg | grep Camera gives : input: UVC Camera (046d:0825) as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.4/1-1.3.4:1.0/input/input326, over and over again

Comment: I guess it really was disconnections... power issues
thanks for the help!